# LatLng as an exploded array in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, maps

I'm retrieving a string of LatLng coordinates from a database and used PHP's explode function and stored it in an array. I want to pass the array from PHP to JavaScript. Also, I want the Polygon function to accept the array and draw the coordinates accordingly. I'm currently stumped. :( Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzZfro&sensor=false">
</script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(8.5000,125.8333);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatLng,
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
           myOptions);
        var davaoCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(7.0644,125.6078),
            new google.maps.LatLng(8.4833,124.6500),
            new google.maps.LatLng(8.5000,125.8333)
        ];

        var davaoCity = new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: davaoCoordinates,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
         });

        davaoCity.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('capdb');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query ="SELECT cap_info.event, cap_info.sendername, cap_info.urgency, cap_area.polygon
    FROM cap_info
    INNER JOIN cap_area ON cap_info.capid = cap_area.capid
    WHERE cap_info.capid =1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result){
    echo "Query Error." . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print.";
    exit;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $event = $row['event'];
    $sender = $row['sendername'];
    $urgency = $row['urgency'];
    $polygon = $row['polygon']."\n";
}
$coordsArray = explode (" ", $polygon);
$count = sizeof($coordsArray);
//$n=0;
//while ($n < $count){
//echo $coordsArray[$n];
//$n++;
//}
?>
```

Comment: One tip: do not use mysql_connect http://php.net/function.mysql-connect If you want javascript to load a bunch of coordinates then your PHP can return JSON. just use json_encode to return it http://www.php.net/json_encode. If you only want to create the points when the page loads then mjayt should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your array looks like, but, In your php, just create the points for the poly with something like below. That should at least help point you in the right direction.

```
$poly = "";

// loop all values
foreach($array as $v) {
    $poly .= "new google.maps.LatLng(".$v."),\n";
}

// add first item from array to close poly
$poly .= "new google.maps.LatLng(".$array[0].")";
```

Then, in your javascript, just echo the values where you need them

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),myOptions);
var davaoCoordinates = [
<?php echo $poly; ?>
];
```

Comment: Thanks! :) 

The coordsArray is just a simple one-dimensional array. The coordinates field from the database just stores it as a varchar. I used the space " " as a delimiter the explode function needed. So from this: "7.0644,125.6078 8.4833,124.6500 8.5000,125.8333".
  
  it becomes this:  
    7.0644,125.6078  
    8.4833,124.6500  
    8.5000,125.8333

So basically, coordsArray[].

Comment: You should be able to just update the loop then. I'll update it quick above.